# Compare two strings to see if there is one character difference

Tags: python, string

If there are two strings given as inputs, how can I check if by *removing only one character in any of the strings, it will become the same as the other string? All the inputs are english characters.

I've tried to use the `Counter` function to see if I could do anything, but this only gives the amount of same characters.

```
from collections import Counter
def Equal_(s1, s2):
    Number = sum((Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)).values())
return Number
```

These should be `False` :

```
Equal_("a", "b")
Equal_("a", "AA")
Equal_("bb", "ba")
```

and these should be `True` :

```
Equal_("qwer", "qwxer")
Equal_("qwe", "qe")
```

Comment: Why this `Equal_("a", "b")` should be false if by replacing `a -> b` I get `b`? The same with `Equal_("bb", "ba")`.

Comment: The problem description is so vague. You say "changing one character" but the examples actually add or remove one character. Also you haven't specified if the order of characters is important or not.

Comment: I changed the description, sorry about that.

Comment: Depending on your reasoning you may find this link educational: https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html 
It is a spell checker (detecting things like off by one character) done in a compact and relatively easy to understand manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ndiff` from the `difflib` module to list differences between two strings:

```
def compareStrings(a, b):
    diff_list = [li for li in difflib.ndiff(a, b) if li[0] != ' ']

    if(len(diff_list) == 1):
        return True

    return False
```

With your examples:

```
print(compareStrings("a", "b"))
print(compareStrings("a", "AA"))
print(compareStrings("bb", "ba"))
print(compareStrings("qwer", "qwxer"))
print(compareStrings("qwe", "qe"))
```

outputs:

```
False
False
False
True
True
```

Demo here: https://repl.it/@glhr/55369976

Comment: Nicely put with the `ndiff` +1. However, where are you using `case_a` and `case_b`?

Comment: What would the time complexity be in Big O notation

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def Equal_(s1, s2):
    for i in range(0,len(s1)):
        if s1[0:i] + s1[i+1:] == s2:
            return True

    for i in range(0,len(s2)):
        if s2[0:i] + s2[i+1:] == s1:
            return True

    return False

print(Equal_("a", "b"))
print(Equal_("a", "AA"))
print(Equal_("bb", "ba"))
print(Equal_("qwer", "qwxer"))
print(Equal_("qwe", "qe"))
```

Output:

```
False
False
False
True
True
```